# Better way to nest if-let in clojure

Tags: if-statement, clojure

Say I have a map of this form:

```
(def m {:a "A" :b "B"})
```

and I want to do something if `:a` and `:b` are both not nil, I can do:

```
(if-let [a (:a m)]
  (if-let [b (:b m)]
      ... etc ))
```

or

```
(if (and (:a m) (:b m))
  (let [{a :a b :b} m]
      ... etc ))
```

or even

```
(if (every? m [:a :b])
  (let [{a :a b :b} m]
      ... etc ))
```

Is there a neater (ie one-line) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a macro may be necessary here to create the behavior you want. I have never written one (yet) but the following representation suggests to me that this might be fairly straightforward:

```
(let [{:keys [a b]} m]
   (when (every? identity [a b])
      (println (str "Processing " a " and " b))))
```

Using the `:keys` form of destructuring binding and `every?` enables a single specification of a vector of keys to destructure and check, and the bound locals are available in a following code block.

This could be used to make a macro such as `(when-every? [keys coll] code-with-bindings)`

I may update this answer with the macro code if I can take the time to work out how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [map destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms) -- a useful feature of Clojure.  This also exploits the facts that `and` is short-circuiting, and any key in the first map not found in the second map gets `nil`, a falsy value:

```
(let [{a :a b :b} {:a 1 :b "blah"}] 
  (and a b (op a b)))
```

Okay, so it's *two* lines instead of one .... also this doesn't distinguish between `nil` and other falsy values.

Answer (score 1):

`not-any?` is a nice shortcut for this:

```
user> (not-any? nil? [(m :a) (m :b)])
true
user> (not-any? nil? [(m :a) (m :b) (m :d)])
false
user>
```

Comment: wouldn't `(every? some? ... )` be better?  that way you could avoid double negation

Comment: not-any? can stop checking when one is found, for a slight time improvement in many cases

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you want to do if the keys have non-nil values or whether you want non-nil keys or values returned. So, I just solved it for non-nil keys being returned.

You'd use the following as an intermediate step as part of a final solution.

I'm showing all the steps I used, not to be pedantic, but to provide a complete answer. The namespace is `repl-test`. It has a main associated with it.

```
repl-test.core=> (def m {:a "A" :b "B" :c nil})
#'repl-test.core/m

repl-test.core=> (keys m)
(:a :c :b)
```

and then finally:

```
; Check key's value to determine what is filtered through.
repl-test.core=> (filter #(if-not (nil? (%1 m)) (%1 m)) (keys m) )
(:a :b)
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way I found an ugly one-liner, which works because `and` returns the last thing in its argument list if they're all true:

```
(if-let [[a b] (and (:a m) (:b m) [(:a m)(:b m)])]
    (println "neither " a " nor " b " is falsey")
    (println "at least one of " a " or " b " is falsey"))
```