# Why don't when-let and if-let support multiple bindings by default?

Tags: clojure

Why don't `when-let` and `if-let` support multiple bindings by default?

So:

```
(when-let [a ...
           b ...]
  (+ a b))
```

...instead of:

```
(when-let [a ...
  (when-let [b ...
    (+ a b)))
```

I am aware that I can write my own macro or use a monad (as described here: http://inclojurewetrust.blogspot.com/2010/12/when-let-maybe.html).

Comment: I wrote a function what you asked for.Hope it helps!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because (for `if-let`, at least) it's not obvious what to do with the "else" cases.

At least, motivated by [Better way to nest if-let in clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673825/better-way-to-nest-if-let-in-clojure) I started to write a macro that did this.  Given

```
(if-let* [a ...
          b ...]
  action
  other)
```

it would generate

```
(if-let [a ...]
  (if-let [b ...]
    action
    ?))
```

and it wasn't clear to me how to continue (there are two places for "else").

You can say that there should be a single alternative for any failure, or none for `when-let`, but if any of the tests mutate state then things are still going to get messy.

In short, it's a little more complicated than I expected, and so I guess the current approach avoids having to make a call on what the solution should be.

Another way of saying the same thing: you're assuming `if-let` should nest like `let`.  A better model might be `cond`, which isn't a "nested if" but more an "alternative if", and so doesn't fit well with scopes... or, yet another way of saying it: `if` doesn't handle this case any better.

Comment: That `if-let*` macro would be a good answer to my question, too ;)

Comment: but it doesn't exist - i couldn't see a good way of handling the "else" parts.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `other` twice? `(if-let [a ...] (if-let [b ...] action other) other))`?

Comment: @andrewcooke "You can say that there should be a single alternative": exactly. Execute `action` when *all* forms evaluate to true, and `other` when at least one is NIL (see also [`whereas`](http://xach.com/naggum/articles/3248033830373991@naggum.no.txt)). I don't understand why you have concerns about mutability, though.

Comment: I agree with @coredump. If the programmer mutates state then they should understand the risks - that's always the case with Clojure. The semantics can be defined. I believe @andrewcooke's concern about tests mutating state is that if they were nested then a nested test would not run if an outer test was false. To that I say, make it clear in the docs if the tests are done in order or an undefined order; and if the tests are short circuited as soon as one is false.

I see no problem with having one alternative. Just treat it like an `and` of all the tests. If all are true then ... else ...

Answer (score 7):

**Here is when-let*:**

```
(defmacro when-let*
  "Multiple binding version of when-let"
  [bindings & body]
  (if (seq bindings)
    `(when-let [~(first bindings) ~(second bindings)]
       (when-let* ~(vec (drop 2 bindings)) ~@body))
    `(do ~@body)))
```

**Usage:**

```
user=> (when-let* [a 1 b 2 c 3]
                (println "yeah!")
                a)
;;=>yeah!
;;=>1


user=> (when-let* [a 1 b nil c 3]
                (println "damn! b is nil")
                a)
;;=>nil
```

**Here is if-let*:**

```
(defmacro if-let*
  "Multiple binding version of if-let"
  ([bindings then]
   `(if-let* ~bindings ~then nil))
  ([bindings then else]
   (if (seq bindings)
     `(if-let [~(first bindings) ~(second bindings)]
        (if-let* ~(vec (drop 2 bindings)) ~then ~else)
        ~else)
     then)))
```

**Usage:**

```
user=> (if-let* [a 1 
                 b 2 
                 c (+ a b)]
              c
              :some-val)
;;=> 3

user=> (if-let* [a 1 b "Damn!" c nil]
              a
              :some-val)
;;=> :some-val
```

**EDIT: It turned out bindings should not be leaked in the else form.**

Comment: A more robust version of this can be found here https://clojure.atlassian.net/browse/CLJ-2007

Answer (score 5):

If you use [`cats`](http://funcool.github.io/cats/latest/), then there is a `mlet` function that you might find useful :

> ```
> (use 'cats.builtin)
> (require '[cats.core :as m])
> (require '[cats.monad.maybe :as maybe])
>
> (m/mlet [x (maybe/just 42)
>          y nil]
>   (m/return (+ x y)))
> ;; => nil
> ```
>
> As you can see, the mlet short-circuits when encountering a nil value.

(from section 6.5.1 nil)