# Making sure a var is bound in Clojure

Tags: clojure, nullpointerexception, ring

In my middleware I'm checking the values of `:session` to see if the user is logged in.

It works great if the values of `:session` are set. Although, I am not sure what the best way to check if `:session` is bound.

```
(defn logged-in-verify
  [ring-handler]
  (fn new-ring-handler
    [request]
    ;;verify that the scrypt hash of email and timestamp matches.
    (let [session   (:session request)
          email     (:ph-auth-email session)
          token     (:ph-auth-token session)
          timestamp (:ph-auth-timestamp session)]
      (if (scryptgen/check (str email timestamp) token)
        (do 
          ;; return response from wrapped handler
          (ring-handler request))
        ;; return error response
        {:status 400, :body "Please sign in."}))))
```

Since I don't check if `:session` is bound, things using this middleware return a `NullPointerException` if it's unset.  What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`when-let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/when-let)  or the similar [`if-let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/if-let) to check whether you actually have a session or not:

```
(defn logged-in-verify
  [ring-handler]
  (fn new-ring-handler
    [request]
    ;;verify that the scrypt hash of email and timestamp matches.
    (if-let [session   (:session request)]
        (let [email     (:ph-auth-email session)
              token     (:ph-auth-token session)
              timestamp (:ph-auth-timestamp session)]
          (if (scryptgen/check (str email timestamp) token)
             ;; return response from wrapped handler
             (ring-handler request))
             ;; return error response
             {:status 400, :body "Please sign in."}))
        ;; do something when there is no session yet
        (generate-new-session-and-redirect))))
```

Comment: I still get a null pointer exception... maybe I'm missing something ... will play around with it.

Comment: Ah, As it turns out the :session is always set, although first it is {}.  adding an additional if-let seems to be the way to go.  thanks

Comment: Then you could go for using `get-in` instead. Given your problem, you would probably would like to have something like `(if-let* [email (get-in request [:session :ph-auth-email] token (get-in request [:session :ph-auth-token] ...)` but `if-let*` doesn't exist. Cf. [a related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676120/why-dont-when-let-and-if-let-support-multiple-bindings-by-default).

Answer (score 2):

Ring requests are just maps, so you can use 'contains?' to see if it contains a particular key, or 'get' to be get the value associated with the key or a default value if the key it is not in the map.